# How can i get the size of dailymotion videos?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I want to save data traffic during the time that user is watching dailymotion video. Is anyone having an idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you clarify what you need and what you're trying to do? you can get video duration through Dailymotion api https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-duration-field but I don't think it will help saving data traffic!

Comment: I need the size of the video (i mean the size, not width or height) for then checking how much data users have been used during video playing.

Answer (score 0):

This info is not available in the API. Note that the data used will depend on the video quality (1080px, 720px, 480px, etc), and that may vary from a user to another, depending on their device, bandwidth, etc. It is automatically chosen by the video player but the user can also decide to specify a quality.

You will see all available fields for a video object in the documentation at: https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video-fields

Comment: Not only that, but since I assume you use dynamic compression the amount of data per time segment can differ wildly, depending on how much the individual frames differ from each other

Comment: So isn't there a solution to get how much data an user used when video has been visualized?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a getimagesize of the thumbnail_url !